# How to solve this script problem in theme directory?

Tags: wp-query, loop, jquery, ajax

I have a **`jQuery Ajax`** call that calls a php script. This call works if the file is in the root of the site but does not work if this php script is in the theme folder . Additionally, I have a 500 error (**Internal Server Error**) or 404 (**Page Not Found**).

My Ajax Call:

```
        $(".buscando").on('click', function( eve ){

            eve.preventDefault();
            var buscando = $('.buscando').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/inc/retorno.php",  <--- this not work
                url: "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/retorno.php",               <--- this work
                data: { buscando: buscando },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data){

                    $("#resultado_pesquisa").html(data);
                    $("#resultado_pesquisa").removeClass("esconder");

                }

            });  

        });
```

> http://pastebin.com/zUfQ70DK <<<< This is **`PHP Script`**

Comment: Use the proper [WordPress way of doing AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: At this moment, I need to know how to solve this problem this way. Thanks for your help.